# Spring Security how to stop creating new CSRF cookie everytime a request is called

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

How to stop replacing CSRF Token for ignoringRequestMatchers? I did not implement the codes below and I am trying to solve someone else problem arised from the implementation

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        // set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
        // add additional same site strict and secure to CookieCsrfTokenRepository
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepo = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        csrfTokenRepo.setCookieCustomizer(cookieBuilder -> cookieBuilder
                .sameSite(Cookie.SameSite.STRICT.attributeValue())
                .secure(true)
                );
        
        return http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepo) // CSRF configure for cookie
                    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler) // CSRF configure for request handler
                    .ignoringRequestMatchers("/user/getUserDetails", "/user/register", "/user/refreshToken") // Ignore CSRF for certain urls
                    //  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#disable-csrf  <== Refer to this
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()) // CORS configurations
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/user/register","/user/login","/user/refreshToken","/home").permitAll()
                    // .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll() uncomment this for static file host
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ) // HTTP Request configurations
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(csrfCookieFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```